# How can data get lost, using sockets from "System.Net.Sockets"?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a C# TCP socket based application, based on the technology from the `System.Net.Sockets` package.

Receiving packets goes as follows:

```
private void OnReceivedData(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Socket was the passed in object
    var sock = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

    // Check if we got any data
    try
    {
        int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive(ar);
        ...
```

When too many data get sent, parts of it are getting lost.

I remember having worked with "Computer Management", "Services and Applications", "Message Queuing", ..., but I don't remember what it was all about.

Does anybody know how I can detect and solve such **apparent** buffer overflooding situations?

**Edit** First attempt

I just tried following way to catch the issue:

```
SocketError socket_ErrorCode;
int nBytesRec = sock.EndReceive(ar, out socket_ErrorCode);
if (socket_ErrorCode != 0)
{
    Log.Error($"Following socket errorcode is found: [{socket_ErrorCode}]");
}
```

=> Although again some packets were lost, that error was not shown.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Data don't get lost in the middle of a TCP connection since TCP is a reliable protocol. Likely your code is wrong, but there are not enough information to point out exactly where it is wrong. A common problem though is treating TCP as a message based protocol and to assume that a single write in the sender will match a single read in the recipient. But this is not the case.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using TcpListener (and `await` instead of `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive`)? Or even better, a higher level network protocol than TCP (given that you apparently want a message-based protocol, while TCP is _stream_-based)?

Comment: @Luaan: I must use TCP for business reasons. The reasons I'm working with `BeginReceive` / `EndReceive` is like so many times in software engineering: I have inherited this program and I'm developing further on it. As we are currently quite far in the progress of the customer project, I would prefer not to change the entire base technology.

Comment: @Dominique read Steffan's comment

Comment: Usually data gets lost because the developer messes up the buffer handling at one or more ends. You write number of bytes into a socket and some number of bytes pop out the other end - "but how can I know I got all the bytes?" - you develop a protocol on top of this byte shuffling, like "The message will be of the format blahblah and each message is terminated with an \n" - you read until you get an `\n` then processes the dat aas one message. If you didn't get your \n you read again. If you get too much you save the overspill for compounding into the next message

Comment: .net has classes that help with this, e.g. streamreader will read read read until it gets a \newline and give you the line, if you use ReadLine - you hand the buffering manipulation off to a well tried and tested class